# how can Calculate difference between two dates (number of days) using linq to entities?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var worker = from w in db.Distributions
                     join d in db.Distributions on w.WorkerId equals d.WorkerId
                     join p in db.Products on d.ProductId equals p.ProductId

                     select new DataBindingProjection
                     {
                         Date = d.DateTime,
                         ProductName = d.Product.ProductName,
                         DistributedPiece = d.Piece,
                         HowManyDays = db.Distributions.Where(r => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(r.DateTime) == DateTime.Now.Date)
                     };

        dataGridView1.DataSource = worker.ToList();
```

//I'm tired for this try various way but still now i face this error..System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.'
**Where HowManyDays is string type variable.
How can solve it?
I want to see :Example - "10 days ago" this type answer.

Comment: Use DbFunctions.DiffDays

Comment: Thank you for your response recently I tried this way but maybe some where mistake.Now I reach my goal after your suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution to get the date difference of two dates:

```
var days = from items in Vals
            select new
            {
                days = items.maxdate - items.mindate
            };

foreach (var day in days)
{
    Console.WriteLine(day.days.TotalDays);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to that error message, linq thinks that `Date` property needs to be converted to an SQL statement.

Try declaring `DateTime.Now.Date` earlier on a separate line before the linq statement, like `var nowDate = DateTime.Now.Date`, then reference `nowDate` in the linq statement instead of `DateTime.Now.Date`

Comment: You might have other problems to deal with after, but this answer deals with your current specific problem.